# getting a google id and an access token from a google username/password

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am creating a headless service that I intend to use to access a third party API.  To do this, I need to authorize myself with this third party API using a google access token.  since I want this service to run in a headless fasion (i.e. no user input), I created a special account with Google and now I want to get the access token and google id using OAuth - the caveat is that this is a headless service, so I need to do this without the 'user' entering their username / password.

how do I do this?

Comment: I am wondering if it would be possible to get an access token using a browser, but making sure that it never expires...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your comment, you can get a refresh token through the web flow. Refresh tokens never expire (although the user can revoke them) and can be used to obtain access tokens as often as needed. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer for more info.